# How would I combine two arrays in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the Objective-C equivalent of the JavaScript `concat()` function?

Assuming that both objects are arrays, how would you combine them?

Comment: It looks like you're doing calendrical operations.  Please consider using `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` and friends to do them for you.  They are not a trivial subject.  Are you taking leap months into account? How about daylight savings time? What about leap seconds? etc.

Comment: @DaveDeLong - Right now I'm porting a small Javascript Library. I will be refactoring code once I'm done with the actual rewrite. My first goal is to get the information in Objective-C and optimize later.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

`NSArray`'s `arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:` is more-or-less equivalent to JavaScript's `.concat()` method:

```
NSArray *newArray=[firstArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:secondArray];
```

Note: If `firstArray` is nil, `newArray` will be nil. This can be fixed by using the following:

```
NSArray *newArray=firstArray?[firstArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:secondArray]:[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:secondArray];
```

If you want to strip-out duplicates:

```
NSArray *uniqueEntries = (NSArray *)[[NSSet setWithArray:newArray] allObjects];
```

Comment: Would this require an `firstArray` to be an `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: @Moshe It returns a new (immutable) NSArray object, and doesn't alter the original array, so it works fine on NSArray objects.

Comment: The method is named arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray (not *in*Array).

Comment: There is a potential problem with the answer, if the firstArray is nil but the second array is not, the newArray is nil.

Comment: Sure, then add:

    `if (!firstArray)
      firstArray = @[ ];`

Comment: then to make sure that you only get unique entries (if that's what you want):

NSArray *uniqueEntries = [[NSSet setWithArray:newArray] allObjects];

Comment: @AndrewBennett please change you comment into snippet, it will be more readable :) btw nice addition to answer!

Comment: Wouldn't turning the array to a set to strip duplicates also lose the ordering?

Answer (score 10):

Here's a symmetric & simple way by just beginning with an empty array:

```
NSArray* newArray = @[];
newArray = [newArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:firstArray];
newArray = [newArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:secondArray];
```